# Regex pattern to find all the digits which don't have the immediate dot character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, regex-group

Can any of you please help me to write a regex pattern for the below requirement?

1. Section tags that don't have numbers
2. All section tag numbers that don't have a dot character followed by.
3. Numbers that are closer to the section tag only that to be considered.

**Test String:**

```
<sectionb>2.3. Optimized test sentence<op>(</op>1,1<cp>)</cp></sectionb>
*<sectiona>2 Surface Model: ONGV<op>(</op>1,1<cp>)</cp></sectiona>*
<sectiona>3. Verification of MKJU<op>(</op>1,1<cp>)</cp> Entity</sectiona>
*<sectionc>3. 2. 1 <txt>Case 1</txt> Annual charges to SGX</sectionc>*
*<sectiona>Compound Interest<role>back</role></sectiona>*
```

**Pattern:**

```
<section[a-z]>[\d]*[^\.]*<\/section[a-z]
```

**Regex Pattern Should Match the below string:**

```
<sectiona>2 Surface Model: ONGV<op>(</op>1,1<cp>)</cp></sectiona>
<sectionc>3. 2 1 <txt>Case 1</txt> Annual charges to SGX</sectionc>
<sectiona>Compound Interest<role>back</role></sectiona>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This matches the updated requirements:

```
<section\w+>(((\d+\.\s*)*(\d+[^\.]))|[^\d]).*?<\/section\w>
```

`<section\w+>` `\w` is mostly the same as `[a-z]` with `+` to allow for 0 or more (`<section>` `<sectionabc>`), remove `+` for exactly one letter

`(\d+\.\s*)*` 0 or more digit/dot/any number of spaces - match updated row 3 where it's now `3. 2. 1` with spaces after dots

`(\d+[^\.])` must match digit without a dot, one or more digits

`((...)|[^\d])` or section does not start with a digit (match row 5)

`.*?` followed by any character, as few as times as possible upto the following `</section` - could likely do this with a look ahead to simplify the regex, but, for me, this keeps the separate "no digits" clause separate.

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/O8EMYP/1)